# Hooking an environment inside `document` environment

Tags: beamer, environments, hooks

I am making a `beamer`-document that is basically a one-page frame. Since don't want to explicitly call the frame inside the environment, I how `\begin{frame}[t]` at the beginning of the document and `\end{frame}` at the end (plus two `\vfill` commands). This is the code:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\AtBeginDocument{\begin{frame}[t]\vfill}
\AtEndDocument{\vfill\end{frame}}

\begin{document}

Cogito ergo sum.

\end{document}
```

Which returns the following error message:

```
File ended while scanning use of \beamer@collect@@body.
```

And here is the [log file](http://txt.do/108jb).

This, I suppose, means that I cannot hook environments to the `document` environment in this way. What would be the right way to do it? Is there a general way to do so for any environment? (That is, not only for `frame`.)

Thanks in advance for the help.

---

**UPDATE:**

Thanks to @koleygr I could use the following code:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\let\olddocument\document
\let\oldenddocument\enddocument

\renewenvironment{document}{\olddocument\begin{frame}[t]\vfill}
  {\vfill\end{frame}\oldenddocument}

\begin{document}

Cogito ergo sum.

\end{document}
```

However, it doesn't work very well when I add another environment as follows:

```
\newcommand{\spacer}{\begin{column}{.02\textwidth}\end{column}}

\let\olddocument\document
\let\oldenddocument\enddocument

\renewenvironment{document}%
  {\olddocument\begin{frame}[t]\vfill%
    \begin{columns}[t]\spacer}
  {\spacer\end{columns}%
    \vfill\end{frame}\oldenddocument}

\begin{document}

Cogito ergo sum.

\end{document}
```

This returns the following error message:

```
File ended while scanning use of \frame.
```

And here is the [log file](http://txt.do/10844).

How should I deal with this? Should I define some commands `\oldolddocument` and `\oldoldenddocument` for storing the recently redefined `document` environment or is there a more straightforward solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edit after OPs edit:**

This should work in this case:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\newcommand{\Lspacer}{\columns[t]\column{.02\textwidth}\column{0.96\textwidth}}
\newcommand{\Rspacer}{\column{.02\textwidth}\endcolumns}

\let\olddocument\document
\let\oldenddocument\enddocument

\renewenvironment{document}%
  {\olddocument\begin{frame}[t]\vfill\par%
    \Lspacer%
    }
  {\Rspacer%
    \vfill\end{frame}\oldenddocument
    }

\begin{document}

Cogito ergo sum.

\end{document}
```

**Old answer:**

You could try this way in this case:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\let\olddocument\document
\let\oldenddocument\enddocument
\renewenvironment{document}{\olddocument\begin{frame}[t]\vfill}
{\vfill\end{frame}\oldenddocument}

\begin{document}

Cogito ergo sum.

\end{document}
```

Your problem is possibly that there are more commands using the `\AtEndDocument` inside `beamer` class and thus they the order of the frame environment `\begin` and `\end` commands is not the expected.

Comment: Thanks @koleygr, it works as it is. However, when I want to add a further environment it crashes again. Please, kindly see my update.

Comment: @Ifba I have edited ... but not really sure about what you want to do with your commands there on the post...

Comment: Fair question, @koleygr. I'm making a template for a `beamerposter` and I don't want to explicitly write the beginning of `frame` and `columns` environment, nor of the spacer first and last columns. I gave a very minimal example (perhaps too minimal) that omits the `beamerposter` package, but I already tested your answer and it works well with it. Thanks again for the answer, and for your patience.

Comment: @lfba happy TeXing ... No patience at all, just asked in order to help more if I would ffind out that more things would be useful for you there and because the way you edited I could not be sure if you want to have the "`\spacer`s" across the title or the whole frame.

Comment: Thanks @koleygr. It's just that I often don't give the proper context to all my questions and, hence, my questions are often not easy to answer. But I'm doing my best to learn. Thanks again.